# PHP SSH read file in chunks by pattern

Tags: php, file, ssh

I have a PHP script that takes a user-supplied string, then SSHs out to a remote server, reads the file into an array, then parses out the request/response blocks containing the string to return to the user.

This implementation does not work with large log files, because PHP runs out of memory trying to store the whole file in an array.

Example data:

```
*** REQUEST

request line 1
request line 2
request line 3
[...]

*** RESPONSE

response line 2
response line 2
response line 3
[...]
[blank line]
```

The length of the requests and responses vary, so I can never be sure how many lines there will be.

How can I read a file in chunks without storing the whole file in memory, while still ensuring I'll always be able to process a full request/response block of data from the log without truncating it?

I feel like I'm just being exceptionally dense about this, since my experience is usually working with whole files or arrays.

Here's my current code (with $search representing the user-supplied string we're looking for in the log), which is putting the whole file into an array first:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$data = '';
while($buffer = fread($stream, 4096)) {
    $data .= $buffer;
}
fclose($stream);
$rawlog = $data;

$logline = explode("\n",$rawlog);
reset($logline);
$block='';

foreach ( $logline as $k => $v ) {
    if ( preg_match("/\*\*\* REQUEST",$v) && $block != '') {
        if ( preg_match("/$search/i",$block) ) {
            $results[] = $block;
        }
        $block=$v . "\n";
    } else {
        $block .= $v . "\n";
    }
}
if ( preg_match("/$search/i",$block) ) {
    $results[] = $block;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might have to mash the parsing routine into the `while` loop that does the reading.

Comment: ^exactly as GigaWatt says, although in that case I'd substitute `fread` with `fgets`.

Comment: However... instead of retrieving the _whole_ file from the server it might be just more efficient to run `grep '*** REQUEST' file.log | grep $search` over SSH. Less traffic, more joy (do `escapeshellarg` though...).

Comment: I get the concept of grabbing X bytes of the file through the `$sftp->get` or `fread` / `fgets` methods. What is stumping me, and what I'm sure is just me being stupid, is how I handle a situation where I grab 2000 bytes from the remote server, but it only contains part of what I need to complete the request/response block (since I'm returning it all, not just a single line). And if I grab another 2000 bytes to complete the chunk from the previous request, how do I work with the remainder to continue grabbing it in pieces until the log is exhausted?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say if this would work for you but if the logs are in files you could use [phpseclib's SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net) (latest Git version).

eg.

If you do `$sftp->get('filename.ext', false, 0, 1000)` it'll download bytes 0-1000 from filename.ext and return a string with those bytes. If you do `$sftp->get('filename.ext', false, 1000, 1000)` it'll download bytes 1000-2000.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command like tail which will get lines from 0 to 99, from 100 to 199, and so on.
This will require more ssh commands, but will not require you to store all result in memory.

Or, you can first store all the output into local file, and after that parse it.